# Import Data into Excel from Access Table, Syntax error in FROM Clause

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I am running this code to import data from Access to Excel and getting a run-time error:

```
 "syntax error in FROM clause."
```

The table in Access has four columns: `Date`, `Time`, `Tank`, `Comments`, and I want to import `Time` and `Tank`, based on a date in the spreadsheet. 
I want to order these columns in the order `Tank`, `Time`.

The error is in the line:

```vb
.Open "Select [Time], [Tank]  FROM [UnitOneRouting] WHERE [Date] = " & RpDate & " ORDER BY Tank, Time", cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
```

Code Snippet:

```vb
Sub ADOImportFromAccessTable()
    Dim DBFullName As String
    Dim TableName As String
    Dim TargetRange As Range
    Dim RpDate As Range

    DBFullName = "U:\Night Sup\Production Report 2003 New Ver 5-28-10_KA.mdb"
    TableName = "UnitOneRouting"
    Worksheets("TankHours").Activate
    Set TargetRange = Range("C5")
    Set RpDate = Range("B2").Cells


    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, intColIndex As Integer
        Set TargetRange = TargetRange.Cells(1, 1)
        ' open the database
        Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
        cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & _
            "U:\Night Sup\Production Report 2003 New Ver 5-28-10_KA.mdb" & ";"
        Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
           With rs
        ' open the recordset
        ' filter rows based on date
            .Open "Select [Time], [Tank]  FROM [UnitOneRouting] WHERE [Date] = " & RpDate & " ORDER BY Tank, Time", cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
         rs.Open , TargetRange
         TargetRange.CopyFromRecordset rs

        End With
        rs.Close
        Set rs = Nothing
        cn.Close
        Set cn = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the `.Open "Select [Time] ...` line and run your code.  When the code breaks on that line, copy the entire SQL string including the first and last quotation marks.  In the immediate window, type "?" and then paste the SQL string and hit enter.  What is the resulting String?  This is exactly what gets sent to Access as the request, so the problem should be visible.  Add it to your question down at the bottom and that will help us help you :D

Comment: First things first, using "Date" as a field name should be avoided as it is reserved.

Comment: Also you are using excel spreadsheet functions on an access DB, there is no "Range" for an access table (AFAIK).  I am a little confused about what you are trying to do here, if you are trying to select values from a table in access as your coding seems to indicate then the first thing is you need to use access functions.

Comment: This is the request that VBA/SQL sends to ACCESS 

Select [Time], [Tank]  FROM [UnitOneRouting] WHERE [Date] = 9/15/2014 ORDER BY Tank, Time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a `SELECT` statement which Access will accept.  Use a string variable to hold the statement.  Then you can `Debug.Print` the variable and inspect the statement text in the Immediate window.  For troubleshooting, you can also copy the statement text from there and paste it into SQL View of a new Access query.

Here is a code example, where I hard-coded the value for `RpDate` ... just to keep it simple.

```vb
Dim RpDate
Dim strSelect As String
RpDate = #9/26/2014#
strSelect = "SELECT u.Time, u.Tank" & vbCrLf & _
    "FROM UnitOneRouting AS u" & vbCrLf & _
    "WHERE u.Date = " & Format(RpDate, "\#yyyy-m-d\#") & vbCrLf & _
    "ORDER BY u.Tank, u.Time;"
Debug.Print strSelect
```

This is the `SELECT` statement produced by that code ...

```sql
SELECT u.Time, u.Tank
FROM UnitOneRouting AS u
WHERE u.Date = #2014-9-26#
ORDER BY u.Tank, u.Time;
```

Once you have a valid Access SQL `SELECT` statement, you will need to fix the recordset `.Open` call to give it acceptable option values.  `adCmdTable` causes an error because your recordset's data source is a `SELECT` statement, not a table.

```vb
' next line throws error -2147217900, "Syntax error in FROM clause."
.Open strSelect, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable

'either of the next 2 lines works ...
'.Open strSelect, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
.Open strSelect, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
```

So I think you're dealing with a situation where the error message is misleading.  *"Syntax error in FROM clause"* suggests the problem is in the `SELECT` statement.  However, once you do have a valid `SELECT`, you will still get that same error text due to `adCmdTable`.  Do not use `adCmdTable` for a `SELECT`.

Comment: This helped a lot. The code ran through to the end and imported the data from the access table. I have two new problems now: The data is still in the order Time, Tank instead of Tank, Time. And it is being sorted (by row) alphabetically based on Tank, but I want it sorted based on time. Should I ask this in a different question?

Comment: `ORDER BY u.Tank, u.Time` tells Access to sort first by `Tank`.  Among rows with the same `Tank` values, they will then be sorted by `Time`.  If that's not the sort order you want, paste the `SELECT` statement text into SQL View of a new Access query.  Then switch to Design View and adjust the ordering to display what you want when you switch to Datasheet View.

Comment: I am doing this programming in VBA-Excel, and to be honest it is the first program I am really doing on my own that is remotely SQL-related. I do not have much idea of what you just mentioned. I just switched the program to have the rows sorted on based on time. What I really want though is to have the columns swapped in Excel. In the Access table, Time is column 2 and Tank is column 3. When I import into Excel, I want Tank to be the first column and Time to be the second. So far it is being imported with Time being before Tank. Can I program that in VBA?

Comment: Do you have MS Access in your MS Office installation?

Comment: Yes I do. I can go ahead and switch that. I just understood what you mentioned. But that's how I want it in the database. It is easier to read that way in Access. But it is easier to read in Excel when it is reversed. Based on how things are set up. To change the set-up will involve a lot more reprogramming than finding a program fix when importing. 
What I can do though, is to select and swap these columns after they are imported, in the same macro.

Comment: Please use the Access query designer to build your query.  After you set the column order and row order to your liking, switch to SQL View to see the SQL statement.  Build that same SQL statement in your Excel VBA code.  If unable to set the column and row order correctly in the query designer, please submit a new question about that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an example of your SQL request?

I think there's a problem in the date's format...
you should try to wrap your date (`RpDate`) whith this char `#`, like this :

```
.Open "Select [Time], [Tank]  FROM [UnitOneRouting] WHERE [Date] = #" & RpDate & "# ORDER BY Tank, Time", cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
```

Answer (score 0):

As my comment mentions I am a little confused by your code here.  You are trying to select records based on their date, but when you dim your RbDate variable you are setting it to a range?  This is not only not a valid property of an Access table, even if it were you cannot compare a date to a range.  If you were in Excel you could

> Dim RbDate as Date
>
> RbDate = ActiveWorksheet.Range("B2").Value

But as you are not in excel this does not apply.  I would suggest using a parameter for date if it will constantly change, otherwise just hardcode the date right into your code in the following way

> Dim RbDate as Date
>
> RbDate = #2017/11/23#

You can then use this as a value in your SQL query string, as currently RbDate is probably empty or simply not comparable to [Date].  You can try this to be sure, run your code by "Stepping", press F8 and each time you do it will execute one line of code, after you get past (at least one line of code after)

> Set RpDate = Range("B2").Cells

hover your curser over "RpDate" and it will tell you what is stored in the variable

Comment: I run the code step by step and get passed that part. The RpDate is a cell in Excel that I cannot afford to hard code. I want to use that date to compare with the dates in the Access table, and select data that matches date. I am doing this programming in VBA-Excel.

Comment: Ah that would be why I was confused, so do what I said with Diming RbDate as a Date and assign it to Activeworksheet.Range("B2").value and see if that helps

Comment: this got me into compile problems.